# public onPostExecute method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using the AsyncTask class, but I am using it as a public class. I would like to run some code after it finishes executing, but I cannot figure out how to do it outside of the class. For example:

```
exampleAsyncTaskClass.execute(params); 
//What can I write here to execute code after the AsyncTask is completed
```

Is there anyway I can execute code after the task completes without using the protected onPostExecute method. Or is there a way that I can make that method unprotected?

Comment: Change `protected` to `public`? I'm not sure what that will accomplish though.

Comment: you can introduce some variable to check if teh task has finished or not.....   for ex   if(isfinished){//execute som ecode}

Comment: @immibis: AsyncTask is a built in class

Comment: @Horatio And your AsyncTask subclass is not.

Comment: @immibis okay so I can override the class as public, but how would I pass in the code for it to execute outside the class?

Comment: @Horatio By putting that code in your `onPostExecute` method. (I assumed you knew how AsyncTask worked and didn't want to use it for some reason; sorry)

Comment: its hard bro, the only thing I can see if that is the approach you want is to extend the activity class then call a method on the activity which excecutes what you want to do... Separate class Asynctask is rarely done after all.

Comment: @Sheychan yeah I am just going to refactor it into one class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass handler into constructor of your task and call it when the task is finished.

Could look like this:

```
public class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{

    private OnPostExecuteHandler handler;

    public SomeTask(OnPostExecuteHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        handler.runOnFinish();
    }

    public interface OnPostExecuteHandler{
        void runOnFinish();
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
new SomeTask(new SomeTask.OnPostExecuteHandler() {
    @Override public void runOnFinish() {
        //will be called when the task is finished
    }
}).execute(someParams);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how I would access that from another class?

Comment: @Horatio added. I would suggest you to read about basics of Java. And only then dive into android development.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.....

```
public class Myclass{
boolean isTaskFinished;
if(isfinsihed){
//execute some code
}

ExampleTask exampe=new ExampleTask();
example.execute;



class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{
private OnPostExecuteHandler handler;

public ExampleTask (OnPostExecuteHandler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

@Override protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    handler.runOnFinish();
}

public interface OnPostExecuteHandler{
    void runOnFinish();
isFinished=true:
    }
}



}
```